# OpenCV Android - Open camera flash

Tags: android, flash, opencv

I want to open the Flash Led in camera once app openCV opens but I have no access to camera :

```
mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_native_surface_view);
```

//This line not working. set method not there

```
mOpenCvCameraView.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE,Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using openCV v3.0.0 you can create new class (from samples tutorial3 with some modyfications):

```
public class Tutorial3View extends JavaCameraView implements PictureCallback {
    private String mPictureFileName;

    public Tutorial3View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public List<String> getEffectList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();
    }
    public boolean isEffectSupported() {
        return (mCamera.getParameters().getFlashMode() != null);
    }
    public String getEffect() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getFlashMode();
    }
    public void setEffect(String effect) {
        mCamera.getParameters();
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(effect);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }
    public List<Size> getResolutionList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    }
    public void setResolution(int w, int h) {
        disconnectCamera();
        mMaxHeight = h;
        mMaxWidth = w;
        connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public Size getResolution() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    }

    public void takePicture(final String fileName) {
        this.mPictureFileName = fileName;
        // Postview and jpeg are sent in the same buffers if the queue is not empty when performing a capture.
        // Clear up buffers to avoid mCamera.takePicture to be stuck because of a memory issue
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

        // PictureCallback is implemented by the current class
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

        // Write the image in a file (in jpeg format)
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFileName);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
        }

    }

    public void cameraRelease() {
        if(mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();
        }
    }
}
```

and then modify your activity (**Tutorial3View** instead **CameraBridgeViewBase**):

```
private Tutorial3View mOpenCVCameraView;   

mOpenCVCameraView = (Tutorial3View) findViewById(R.id.camera_surface_view);
mOpenCVCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
mOpenCVCameraView.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this);

//then you can set effect, for example torch:
mOpenCVCameraView.setEffect(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi Guys In [OpenCV Camera](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/android/tutorial-3-cameracontrol/src/org/opencv/samples/tutorial3/Tutorial3View.java) you can enable flash with the following easy steps (My Torch is working in opencv camera):

1) Add this line

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class Tutorial3View extends com.lenviz.avi.utils.JavaCameraView implements Camera.PictureCallback {
    private String mPictureFileName;

    public Tutorial3View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public List<String> getEffectList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();
    }
    public boolean isEffectSupported() {
        return (mCamera.getParameters().getFlashMode() != null);
    }
    public String getEffect() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getFlashMode();
    }

    public void setEffect(String effect) {
        if (mCamera==null)
            try {
                mCamera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
                /*mCamera.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE,
                        Highgui.CV_CAP_ANDROID_FLASH_MODE_TORCH);*/

                Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
                p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();

            }catch (RuntimeException ex){}

       /* mCamera.getParameters();
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        mCamera.startPreview();*/
    }

    public List<Camera.Size> getResolutionList() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    }
    public void setResolution(int w, int h) {
        disconnectCamera();
        mMaxHeight = h;
        mMaxWidth = w;
        connectCamera(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public Camera.Size getResolution() {
        return mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    }

    public void takePicture(final String fileName) {
        this.mPictureFileName = fileName;
        // Postview and jpeg are sent in the same buffers if the queue is not empty when performing a capture.
        // Clear up buffers to avoid mCamera.takePicture to be stuck because of a memory issue
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

        // PictureCallback is implemented by the current class
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // The camera preview was automatically stopped. Start it again.
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);

        // Write the image in a file (in jpeg format)
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mPictureFileName);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
        }

    }

    public void cameraRelease() {
        if(mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();
        }
    }
}
```

2) Add the following code in JavaCameraView class inside the initilizeCamera method after 168 line number

```
List<String> FlashMode = params.getSupportedFlashModes();  //Vinod Code working torch wala
                    if (FlashMode != null && FlashMode.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH))
                    {
                        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    }
```

or you can replace the JavaCameraView class with the following code below:

```
package org.opencv.android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;

import org.opencv.BuildConfig;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;


public class JavaCameraView extends CameraBridgeViewBase implements PreviewCallback {

    private static final int MAGIC_TEXTURE_ID = 10;
    private static final String TAG = "JavaCameraView";

    private byte mBuffer[];
    private Mat[] mFrameChain;
    private int mChainIdx = 0;
    private Thread mThread;
    private boolean mStopThread;

    protected Camera mCamera;
    protected JavaCameraFrame[] mCameraFrame;
    private SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture;
    private int mPreviewFormat = ImageFormat.NV21;

    public static class JavaCameraSizeAccessor implements ListItemAccessor {

        @Override
        public int getWidth(Object obj) {
            Camera.Size size = (Camera.Size) obj;
            return size.width;
        }

        @Override
        public int getHeight(Object obj) {
            Camera.Size size = (Camera.Size) obj;
            return size.height;
        }
    }

    public JavaCameraView(Context context, int cameraId) {
        super(context, cameraId);
    }

    public JavaCameraView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected boolean initializeCamera(int width, int height) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Initialize java camera");
        boolean result = true;
        synchronized (this) {
            mCamera = null;

            if (mCameraIndex == CAMERA_ID_ANY) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Trying to open camera with old open()");
                try {
                    mCamera = Camera.open();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Camera is not available (in use or does not exist): " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }

                if(mCamera == null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
                    boolean connected = false;
                    for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); ++camIdx) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to open camera with new open(" + Integer.valueOf(camIdx) + ")");
                        try {
                            mCamera = Camera.open(camIdx);
                            connected = true;
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Camera #" + camIdx + "failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                        if (connected) break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
                    int localCameraIndex = mCameraIndex;
                    if (mCameraIndex == CAMERA_ID_BACK) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to open back camera");
                        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
                        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); ++camIdx) {
                            Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
                            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                                localCameraIndex = camIdx;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (mCameraIndex == CAMERA_ID_FRONT) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Trying to open front camera");
                        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
                        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); ++camIdx) {
                            Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
                            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                                localCameraIndex = camIdx;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (localCameraIndex == CAMERA_ID_BACK) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Back camera not found!");
                    } else if (localCameraIndex == CAMERA_ID_FRONT) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Front camera not found!");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to open camera with new open(" + Integer.valueOf(localCameraIndex) + ")");
                        try {
                            mCamera = Camera.open(localCameraIndex);
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Camera #" + localCameraIndex + "failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (mCamera == null)
                return false;

            /* Now set camera parameters */
            try {
                Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                Log.d(TAG, "getSupportedPreviewSizes()");
                List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

                if (sizes != null) {
                    /* Select the size that fits surface considering maximum size allowed */
                    Size frameSize = calculateCameraFrameSize(sizes, new JavaCameraSizeAccessor(), width, height);

                    /* Image format NV21 causes issues in the Android emulators */
                    if (Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
                            || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
                            || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
                            || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
                            || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
                            || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
                            || (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
                            || "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT))
                        params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.YV12);  // "generic" or "android" = android emulator
                    else
                        params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21); //ImageFormat.NV21) vinod changed on 15.10.18

                    mPreviewFormat = params.getPreviewFormat();
                    params.setPreviewSize((int)640, (int)480);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Set preview size to " + Integer.valueOf((int)frameSize.width) + "x" + Integer.valueOf((int)frameSize.height));
                    //params.setPreviewSize((int)frameSize.width, (int)frameSize.height);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH && !Build.MODEL.equals("GT-I9100"))
                        params.setRecordingHint(true);

                    List<String> FocusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
                    if (FocusModes != null && FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO))
                    {
                        params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
                    }

                    /*List<String> FlashMode = params.getSupportedFlashModes();  //Vinod Code working torch wala
                    if (FlashMode != null && FlashMode.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH))
                    {
                        params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    }*/

                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                    params = mCamera.getParameters();

                    mFrameWidth = params.getPreviewSize().width;
                    mFrameHeight = params.getPreviewSize().height;

                    if ((getLayoutParams().width == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) && (getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))
                        mScale = Math.min(((float)height)/mFrameHeight, ((float)width)/mFrameWidth);
                    else
                        mScale = 0;

                    if (mFpsMeter != null) {
                        mFpsMeter.setResolution(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);
                    }

                    int size = mFrameWidth * mFrameHeight;
                    size  = size * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(params.getPreviewFormat()) / 8;
                    mBuffer = new byte[size];

                    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
                    mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);

                    mFrameChain = new Mat[2];
                    mFrameChain[0] = new Mat(mFrameHeight + (mFrameHeight/2), mFrameWidth, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                    mFrameChain[1] = new Mat(mFrameHeight + (mFrameHeight/2), mFrameWidth, CvType.CV_8UC1);

                    AllocateCache();

                    mCameraFrame = new JavaCameraFrame[2];
                    mCameraFrame[0] = new JavaCameraFrame(mFrameChain[0], mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);
                    mCameraFrame[1] = new JavaCameraFrame(mFrameChain[1], mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(MAGIC_TEXTURE_ID);
                        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
                    } else
                       mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);

                    /* Finally we are ready to start the preview */
                    Log.d(TAG, "startPreview");
                    mCamera.startPreview();
                }
                else
                    result = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                result = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void releaseCamera() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);

                mCamera.release();
            }
            mCamera = null;
            if (mFrameChain != null) {
                mFrameChain[0].release();
                mFrameChain[1].release();
            }
            if (mCameraFrame != null) {
                mCameraFrame[0].release();
                mCameraFrame[1].release();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean mCameraFrameReady = false;

    @Override
    protected boolean connectCamera(int width, int height) {

        /* 1. We need to instantiate camera
         * 2. We need to start thread which will be getting frames
         */
        /* First step - initialize camera connection */
        //setDisplayOrientation(mCamera, 90);
        /*try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(getHolder());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to camera");
        if (!initializeCamera(width, height))
            return false;

        mCameraFrameReady = false;

        /* now we can start update thread */
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting processing thread");
        mStopThread = false;
        mThread = new Thread(new CameraWorker());
        mThread.start();

        return true;
    }

    protected void setDisplayOrientation(Camera camera, int angle){
        Method downPolymorphic;
        try
        {
            downPolymorphic = camera.getClass().getMethod("setDisplayOrientation", new Class[] { int.class });
            if (downPolymorphic != null)
                downPolymorphic.invoke(camera, new Object[] { angle });
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disconnecting from camera");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void disconnectCamera() {
        /* 1. We need to stop thread which updating the frames
         * 2. Stop camera and release it
         */
        Log.d(TAG, "Disconnecting from camera");
        try {
            mStopThread = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "Notify thread");
            synchronized (this) {
                this.notify();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for thread");
            if (mThread != null)
                mThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mThread =  null;
        }

        /* Now release camera */
        releaseCamera();

        mCameraFrameReady = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] frame, Camera arg1) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "Preview Frame received. Frame size: " + frame.length);
        synchronized (this) {
            mFrameChain[mChainIdx].put(0, 0, frame);
            mCameraFrameReady = true;
            this.notify();
        }
        if (mCamera != null)
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
    }

    private class JavaCameraFrame implements CvCameraViewFrame {
        @Override
        public Mat gray() {
            return mYuvFrameData.submat(0, mHeight, 0, mWidth);
        }

        @Override
        public Mat rgba() {
            if (mPreviewFormat == ImageFormat.NV21)
                Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);
            else if (mPreviewFormat == ImageFormat.YV12)
                Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGB_I420, 4);  // COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YV12 produces inverted colors
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Preview Format can be NV21 or YV12");

            return mRgba;
        }

        public JavaCameraFrame(Mat Yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
            super();
            mWidth = width;
            mHeight = height;
            mYuvFrameData = Yuv420sp;
            mRgba = new Mat();
        }

        public void release() {
            mRgba.release();
        }

        private Mat mYuvFrameData;
        private Mat mRgba;
        private int mWidth;
        private int mHeight;
    };

    private class CameraWorker implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            do {
                boolean hasFrame = false;
                synchronized (JavaCameraView.this) {
                    try {
                        while (!mCameraFrameReady && !mStopThread) {
                            JavaCameraView.this.wait();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (mCameraFrameReady)
                    {
                        mChainIdx = 1 - mChainIdx;
                        mCameraFrameReady = false;
                        hasFrame = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!mStopThread && hasFrame) {
                    if (!mFrameChain[1 - mChainIdx].empty())
                        deliverAndDrawFrame(mCameraFrame[1 - mChainIdx]);
                }
            } while (!mStopThread);
            Log.d(TAG, "Finish processing thread");
        }
    }

    public void setFocusMode(Context context, int type) {

        if (mCamera==null)
            try {

                mCamera = android.hardware.Camera.open();
                Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();

                p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();

            }catch (RuntimeException ex){}
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
        mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean b, Camera camera) {
            }
        });

        List<String> FocusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
        List<String> FlashModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();

        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO))
                    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                else
                    // Toast.makeText(item, "Auto Mode is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            case 1:
                if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO))
                    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
                else
                    //  Toast.makeText(item, "Continuous Mode is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            case 2:
                if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_EDOF))
                    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_EDOF);
                else
                    // Toast.makeText(item, "EDOF Mode is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            case 3:
                if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED))
                    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED);
                else
                    // Toast.makeText(item, "Fixed Mode is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            case 4:
                if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY))
                    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);
                else
                    //  Toast.makeText(item, "Infinity Mode is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            case 5:
                if (FocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO))
                    params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO);
                else
                    //  Toast.makeText(item, "Macro Mode is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            case 6:
                if (FlashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH))
                    params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                else
                    //  Toast.makeText(item, "Auto Mode not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
        }

        mCamera.setParameters(params);
    }

}
```